# Interrupting and Joining NSThread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, interrupt, nsthread

I want to do interrupt and join on an instance of NSThread like I do in Java. I have read the [NSThread Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but I can't find such methods. What can I do to have the same effect?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if that is possible with NSThreads...

In the concurrency programming guide there is a [mention of replacing thread joins](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW6)(see **Replacing Thread Joins Section** with GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). There is also a mention about getting NSOperations to wait on each other [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW40) (scroll all the way down to **Waiting for Operations to Finish**).

In the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html), under section **Setting the Detached State of a Thread** Apple mentions the following:

> If you do want to create joinable threads, the only way to do so is
>   using POSIX threads. POSIX creates threads as joinable by default. To
>   mark a thread as detached or joinable, modify the thread attributes
>   using the pthread_attr_setdetachstate function prior to creating the
>   thread. After the thread begins, you can change a joinable thread to a
>   detached thread by calling the pthread_detach function. For more
>   information about these POSIX thread functions, see the pthread man
>   page. For information on how to join with a thread, see the
>   pthread_join man page.